# Tips for Increasing the Effectiveness of this R Code

Tags: html, r, json, loops

I am writing a loop (in R) to webscrape Reddit posts - using Reddit's API ("Pushshift").

Essentially, I would like to get every comment that contains the word "Trump" between now and until 20,000 hours ago at an hourly basis. The API stores the comments in a JSON frame - I wrote the following code in R to obtain these comments (note - I made it so that the results are saved after every 200 iterations in case of a crash):

```
library(jsonlite)

part1 = "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
part2 = "h&before="
part3 = "h&size=500"

results = list()
for (i in 1:20000)
{tryCatch({
    {
        url_i<-  paste0(part1, i+1,  part2, i,  part3)
        r_i <-  data.frame(fromJSON(url_i))
        results[[i]] <- r_i

myvec_i <- sapply(results, NROW)

print(c(i, sum(myvec_i))) 
       
        ifelse(i %% 200 == 0, saveRDS(results, "results_index.RDS"), "" )
    }
}, error = function(e){})
}
final = do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
saveRDS(final, "final.RDS")
```

The code runs - but I am looking for tips to increase the speed and efficiency of this code. For example, I have noticed that:

- Sometimes this code seems to take a really long time on certain iterations
- I also have a feeling that as the "list" grows in size and the global environment with R becomes more full, things are also slowing down.
- Sometimes, the webscraping stops collecting new results (i.e. I added a statement which shows the cumulative number of results that have been collected at each iteration - sometimes, this number stops updating)
- I used "tryCatch()" to skip errors to prevent the loop from crashing - but perhaps there might have been some way around this that could have potentially resulted in more Reddit comments being scraped?

Could someone please recommend some tips on how to optimize and speed this code up? Perhaps someone could try running this code and let me know what they think?

Thank you!

Comment: Get arrow package.  Save each r_i as a parquet file and then when the loop is over, open all the files as a dataset.  There's no reason to make the list grow and resave everything that you've already saved. Just make the incremental saves.

Comment: Don't use `ifelse()` for control flow--it's for vectors and data. Use `if() {} else {}` for control flow like this. And yes, for a very large data set that you're saving incrementally, I wouldn't keep the whole thing in memory during the loop. Dean's suggestion is a very good one; alternately you could even just append the results to the same file to keep things all in one place.

Comment: Also, generally you want to do as little inside the loop as possible. Doing a `paste0` at every iteration will be slower than doing a single `paste0` before the loop.  That time is probably miniscule compared to the time for the API to return, so it probably won't make a noticeable difference in this case, but that's the sort of best practice that you should be thinking about in general to speed up the loop. You can define `ii = 1:20000` and do `urls = paste0(part1, ii+1,  part2, ii,  part3)` and then inside the loop use `urls[i]`.

Comment: But overall, this is probably too opinion-based for Stack Overflow--I'd suggest posting at codereview.stackexchange instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will check out this new community on stackexchange!

Comment: @ Dean MacGregor: Can you please show me an example of this if you have time? Thank you!

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: Can you please show me an example of this if you have time? Thank you!

Comment: @antonoyaro8: check this link https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/

Comment: Have you profiled your code? If the majority of the time is needed to download the data from the API, there is likely nothing you can optimize in your R code. Your issue with some iterations taking long could be because the API is having issues because of too many requests or it might even be throttled. Maybe the API allows getting all data at once?

Comment: @ Roland: can you please explain what you mean by "profiled"? thanks!

Comment: What about this: Change `size=500` to a much much bigger number such as `size=100000`, download the files to your desk. This is slow but if you crash you can always continue from whichever file was last downloaded. The size seems to be capped, but the cap is higher than 500 and downloading to desk also allows you to look into why you are getting errors on any individual file. Once everything has been downloaded, your bottleneck will be your power and not the API.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do : 1) save the data.frame into a ".RData file" at each iteration. You need less memory when you do this because you do not store data in the RAM 2) use parallel calculations. Here is an example :

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(RSelenium)

fn_Par <- function(core_Id, all_Index, list_remDr, nb_Core)
{
  library(jsonlite)
  library(RSelenium)
  remDr <- list_remDr[[core_Id]]
  remDr$open()

  setwd("D:\\")
  part1 <- "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
  part2 <- "h&before="
  part3 <- "h&size=500"
  
  nb_Index_All <- length(all_Index)
  nb_Id_Per_Core <- floor(nb_Index_All / nb_Core)
  index_To_Extract <- all_Index[(1 + (core_Id - 1) * nb_Id_Per_Core) : min((core_Id * nb_Id_Per_Core), nb_Index_All)]

  for(i in index_To_Extract)
  {
    url_i <-  paste0(part1, i + 1,  part2, i,  part3)
    remDr$navigate(url_i)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("css selector", 'body > pre')
    r_i <-  tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(web_Obj$getElementText()[[1]])), error = function(e) NA)

    if(is.null(dim(r_i)) == FALSE)
    {
      Sys.sleep(10)
      remDr$navigate(url_i)
      web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("css selector", 'body > pre')
      r_i <-  tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(web_Obj$getElementText()[[1]])), error = function(e) NA)
    }
    
    save(r_i, file = paste0(i, "_core_Id_", core_Id, ".RData"))
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
}

nb_CPU <- 4
cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(nb_CPU)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = cluster)

list_remDr <- list()
list_rd <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_CPU)
{
  print(i)
  port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
  list_rd[[i]] <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
  list_remDr[[i]] <- list_rd[[i]]$client
}

parLapply(cluster, X = 1 : nb_CPU, fun = fn_Par, all_Index = 1 : 2000, list_remDr = list_remDr, nb_Core = nb_CPU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

fn_Par <- function(core_Id, all_Index, nb_Core)
{
  library(jsonlite)

  setwd("D:\\")
  part1 <- "https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment/?q=trump&after="    
  part2 <- "h&before="
  part3 <- "h&size=500"
  
  nb_Index_All <- length(all_Index)
  nb_Id_Per_Core <- floor(nb_Index_All / nb_Core)
  index_To_Extract <- all_Index[(1 + (core_Id - 1) * nb_Id_Per_Core) : min((core_Id * nb_Id_Per_Core), nb_Index_All)]
  
  for(i in index_To_Extract)
  {
    url_i <-  paste0(part1, i + 1,  part2, i,  part3)
    r_i <- tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(url_i)), error = function(e) NA)
    
    if(is.null(dim(r_i)) == TRUE)
    {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      r_i <- tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(url_i)), error = function(e) NA)
    }
    
    if(is.null(dim(r_i)) == TRUE)
    {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      r_i <- tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(url_i)), error = function(e) NA)
    }
    
    if(is.null(dim(r_i)) == TRUE)
    {
      Sys.sleep(5)
      r_i <- tryCatch(data.frame(fromJSON(url_i)), error = function(e) NA)
    }
    
    save(r_i, file = paste0(i, "_core_Id_", core_Id, ".RData"))
  }
}

nb_CPU <- 4
cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(nb_CPU)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = cluster)
parLapply(cluster, X = 1 : nb_CPU, fun = fn_Par, all_Index = 1 : 2000, nb_Core = nb_CPU)
```